# Render module in the right position from code (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In my component view, I can show a module by this code:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_login');
$html = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
echo $html;
```

or

```
echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadmodule login}');
```

But that will usually place the module in the middle of the screen in the main-content div.

How can I place the module in the position defined in the module params?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how the admin template Isis renders the quickicons module on the home page or at how the error page in protostar renders the search modules.

```
$this->searchmodules = JModuleHelper::getModules('position-0');
                foreach ($this->searchmodules as $searchmodule)
                {
                    $output = JModuleHelper::renderModule($searchmodule, array('style' => 'none'));
                    $params = new JRegistry;
                    $params->loadString($searchmodule->params);
                    echo $output;
                }
```

You just want one module, but you get the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

You can Pass the module parameters too.

```
   $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
   $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

   $Module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

   $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";
   $Module->params = $Params;
   echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

This may help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can't, jdoc includes in the template are processed after the component has finished producing its output.

Why not let Joomla render the modules in the right positions? that should be one of the reasons for using it, i.e. taking care of placement and order of modules.

If you have other reasons for doing this, please explain further.